# Manage objects in the global environment in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

Here is my RStudio version.

```
rstudioapi::versionInfo()
$version
[1] ‘1.1.447’
```

I find in the top right side, I can get the info of all objects in the global envrionment. 
In the `grid` mode, I can do some `dplyr`'s style functions, such as `filter` and `arrange`.

[image]

Is there any way to get this info into a data frame, so I can manipulate it by `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2):

You can approximate the information in RStudio's environment tab with something like...

```
data(iris)
data(mtcars)
x <- 1:3
y <- "yes"

ls_vec <- ls()
ls_list <- vector('list', length(ls_vec))
for (i in seq_along(ls_vec)) {
  ls_list[[i]] <-
    data.frame(
      Name = deparse(ls_vec[i]),
      Type = class(get(ls_vec[i])),
      Length = length(get(ls_vec[i])),
      Size = format(object.size(get(ls_vec[i])))
    )
}

Reduce(rbind, ls_list)
#        Name       Type Length       Size
# 1       "i"    integer      1   56 bytes
# 2    "iris" data.frame      5 7256 bytes
# 3 "ls_list"       list      7 5064 bytes
# 4  "ls_vec"  character      7  504 bytes
# 5  "mtcars" data.frame     11 7208 bytes
# 6       "x"    integer      3   64 bytes
# 7       "y"  character      1  112 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I copy it to write a user-defined-function.